# Best way to write hash map with sparse writes and many reads

Tags: java, performance

I need to write a hash map in Java which will be used across threads mostly for reads. Consider a situation in which clients write to the hash map only once(only 10 or 15 entries max), but the key and value comes from the client. This means that I do not know the key/value pairs in advance.After once writing them, they read many times simultaneously.

More like the below code snippet in an efficient way:

```
public String getPS(String query) {
    //put into map if not present
    if(psMap.get(query) == null){
        synchronized (this) {
            if(psMap.get(query) == null){
                //test1 is just a sample  value
                psMap.put(query,"test1");
            }
        }
    }
    return psMap.get(query);

}
```

Comment: Look into http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: I would change `synchronized (this)` to `synchronized (psMap)` but other than that it looks fine.

Comment: What makes you think this isn't efficient enough? I bet it the '10 or 15' times the entry isn't null, doesn't slow down your app.

Comment: I think you should take care of "remove()" method as well. I guess you should use ConcurrentHashMap instead.

Comment: Hi Kartic, I will never be removing entries during the lifetime of the server. @slim : All the clients(around 70 - 80) might make burst calls to the server at any time and I am finding the best way to write the hashmap.  alfasin how will that help?

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap` assumes that the most common operation is retrieving a value, so it is already optimized for the get operations. It even has the putIfAbsent method, so you don't have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentHashMap has concurrent access and the ability to remember a computed value.  Note: this will be called only once per key.

```
public String getPS(String query) {
    //put into map a computed value if not present
    return psMap.computeIfAbsent(query, $ -> "test1");
}
```